# Importing elevation data into geoviews/holoviews (data format)

Tags: bokeh, raster, holoviews, geoviews

How do you import other raster formats into geoviews/holoviews other than the netCDF files shown in the tutorials? For example I want to import an ESRI .bil file and wrap it into a geoviews image but it is not importing correctly. Is there a way to do this, am I missing a step?

Ultimately I want to be able to project point data onto the raster image at the correct lat, long positions to extract data, but I can't seem to get the points projected in the correct positions.

```
from cartopy import crs
import holoviews as hv
import xarray as xr
import geoviews as gv
import pandas as pd
from osgeo import gdal



kdims = ['easting', 'northing']
vdims = ['elevation']
xr_raster = gv.Dataset(DEM, kdims=kdims, vdims=vdims, crs=crs.PlateCarree())

image = gv.Image(xr_raster, crs=crs.PlateCarree()) (style={'cmap':'inferno'})

image
```

This provides this error: TypeError: shape() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gridded'

```
import iris
iris_raster = iris.load_cube('/path/to/raster.bil')
```

This errors as: ValueError: No format specification could be found for the given buffer.

I have only succeeded in importing the data using gdal and then plotting it as a Holoviews Raster or Geoviews Image:

```
Test = gdal.Open(Data_path + "DEM.bil")
DEM = Test.ReadAsArray()

hv.notebook_extension()
%opts Raster [xrotation=20] Points (color='r')[xrotation=20]

#Import point data
df = pd.read_csv(path+name)
stream_dataset = gv.Dataset(df, kdims=['x', 'y'], vdims=['elevation', 'chi', 'flow_distance'])
stream = hv.Points(stream_dataset)

#Import raster
raster = hv.Raster(DEM)(style={'cmap':'inferno'}) 
image = gv.Image(DEM, crs=crs.PlateCarree()) (style={'cmap':'inferno'})

raster + stream + image
```

This is the result:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIOTl.png)

Comment: Can you share an example of the .bil file?

Comment: Yes, here is an example: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v6jm4oq0w9buq11/AABnswsdFwOtK5BcqmLWEVvka?dl=0)

Comment: Sorry I cannot get geoviews working correctly atm.

Comment: Maybe let me rephrase the above question simply:  What kinds of data formats does holoviews or geoviews accept?